# Impossibility of geometrical tools that solve equations of degree five

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry

At Hartshorne, [Geometry: Euclid and beyond](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2002-39-04/S0273-0979-02-00949-7/S0273-0979-02-00949-7.pdf) (1997), p. 4, I read:

[image]

Can from this and [Abel-Ruffini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) be derived, that there are no (inherently physical) tools (like ordinary straightedge, marked ruler, compass, and for example spirals) that correspond exactly to the solution of equations of degree five?